# CMB2 Form Throws No Input File Specified in custom WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm using the CMB2 plugin, integrated into my custom WordPress plugin, to create a form that will be used by folks who want to sign up for a registry.  I cloned the CMB2 repo into my WordPress custom plugin and setup as directed.

My submit function is as follows:

```
/**
* Register form and fields for our Registrant Form
*/
  function qfpplugin_registrant_submit(){
     $cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'                =>  'registrnat-form',
    'object_types'      =>  array( 'post' ),
    'hookup'            =>  false,
    'save_fields'       =>  true,
  ) );

 $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'              =>  __( 'First Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
    'id'                =>  'firstname',
    'type'              =>  'text',
    'default'           =>  __( 'First Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
 ));

 $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'              =>  __('Middle Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
    'id'                =>  'middlename',
    'type'              =>  'text',
    'default'           =>  __( 'Middle Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
 ));

 $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'              =>  __( 'Last Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
    'id'                =>  'lastnmae',
    'type'              =>  'text',
    'default'           =>  __( 'Last Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
 ));

 $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'              =>  __( 'Company Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
    'id'                =>  'companyname',
    'type'              =>  'text',
    'default'           =>  __( 'Company Name', 'qfpplugin' ),
 ));

 $cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'              =>  __( 'Date of Birth', 'qfpplugin' ),
    'id'                =>  'dateofbirth',
    'type'              =>  'text_date'
 ));


 //TODO: Need to add the rest of the registrant form fields.

 }

add_action( 'cmb2_init', 'qfpplugin_registrant_submit' );

/*
* Sets the registrant-form field values.
* @return string
*/
function qfpplugin_set_default_from_posted_values( $args, $field ) {
  if ( ! empty( $_POST[ $field->id() ] ) ) {
    return $_POST[ $field->id() ];
  }
  return '';
}

/*
* Get the registrant-form cmb instance
*
* @return CMB2 object
*/
function qfpplugin_registrant_cmb2_get() {
//Use metabox id of registant-form
$metabox_id = 'registrant-form';

//Ojbect ID not applicable
$object_id = 'fake-object-id';

//Get CMB2 metabox object
return cmb2_get_metabox( $metabox_id, $object_id );
}

/*
* Handles the registrant form shortcode.
* @param array $atts Array of shortdcoce attributes.
* @return string Form HTML
*/
function qfpplugin_do_registrant_submit_shortcode( $atts = array() ) {

   global $post;

   if( @ current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
    return __( 'You do not have permission to edit this post.', 'lang_domain' );
}

//Set Wordpress ID
if (! isset( $atts[ 'post_id' ] ) ) {
    $atts[ 'post_id' ] = $post->ID;
}

//Throw error if no metabox ID is set.
if( ! isset( $atts[ 'post_id' ] ) ) {
    return __( "Please add an 'id' attribute to specify the form to display.", 'lang_domain' );
}

$metabox_id = esc_attr( $atts[ 'id' ] );
$object_id = absint( $atts[ 'post_id' ] );

$form = cmb2_get_metabox_form( $metabox_id, $object_id );

return $form;
}
add_shortcode( 'registrant_form', 'qfpplugin_do_registrant_submit_shortcode' );
```

I added shortcode `registrant_form id="registrant-form"` to the page which is visible on the front end of the site.  When I view the page, I receive the error in my question title.  How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Could you reduce the code a bit? It's kinda hard to skim

Comment: @admcfajn I removed some of the code as per your request.  Appreciate your help.